PyWebIO: stream logger to output
I'm writing a simple PyWebIO setup and am wondering whether I can link an instance of  pywebio.output.put_scrollable with the python logging module. I have a logger set up, and would love to be able to stream the logs directly to a pywebio output box.
Is it possible to stream to a pywebio output block, or is it only capable of rendering static text?
